# Why different output is obtained for the same code (Mathematica 10.1)?

Tags: broken-code

I wrote some code in Mathematica:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
w = 1/H[x] D[q[x], x] (\[Eta][x] - z) + 
   q[x]/H[x] D[H[x], x] (1 - (\[Eta][x] - z)/(\[Eta][x] - Zb[x])) + 
   q[x]/H[x] D[Zb[x], x];
der = Simplify[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]w\)];
dpdz = -(q[x]/H[x] der + w D[w, z] + g);
int = Integrate[dpdz, {z, Z0, Z1}];
Simplify[int] /. {Z0 -> z, Z1 -> \[Eta], q[x] -> q, 
  H[x] -> H, \[Eta][x] -> \[Eta], Zb[x] -> Zb}
```

After I execute it for a first time (after turning on the Mathematica) I get some output. But when I press shift+enter multiple times, then after third time I get different output. Can anybody confirm such behaviour?

Comment: It gives me the same output in V10.1

Comment: @Kuba The same as mine? Or all the time the same?

Comment: I don't know what's your output but I get: `1/2 (z-\[Eta]) (2 g+(1/(H^3 (Zb-\[Eta])^2))(q (Zb-\[Eta]) (H^\[Prime])[x] ((z-\[Eta]) (Zb-\[Eta]) (q^\[Prime])[x]+q ((z-2 Zb+\[Eta]) (H^\[Prime])[x]+2 (-Zb+\[Eta]) (Zb^\[Prime])[x]))+H ((z-\[Eta]) (Zb-\[Eta])^2 (q^\[Prime])[x]^2+q (Zb-\[Eta]) ((z-\[Eta]) (H^\[Prime])[x] (q^\[Prime])[x]+(Zb-\[Eta]) (2 (q^\[Prime])[x] (\[Eta]^\[Prime])[x]-(z-\[Eta]) (q^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]))+q^2 ((z-2 Zb+\[Eta]) ((H^\[Prime])[x] ((H^\[Prime])[x]+(Zb^\[Prime])[x]-(\[Eta]^\[Prime])[x])+(-Zb+\[Eta]) (H^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x])+2 (Zb-\[Eta])^2 (Zb^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]))))`

Comment: @Kuba This is the oputput i get always at the third execution of the code. When I run the code for the first time I get different output.

Comment: I seem to get the same output no matter how many times I evaluate this code (starting in a fresh session).  I am using 10.1 under Windows.  Start by turning of the **predictive interface** (suggestions bar) if you have not done so already.

Comment: How long does that `Simplify` take on your computer? If your computer is very slow it could happen that you run into the `TimeConstraint` that is set for `Simplify` when evaluating the first time. Following evaluations will then take advantage of cached intermediate results and get further in the evaluation and thus return a different result. If that's the case I think it is a known problem but not "broken-code"...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Well my PC i quite fast, so I wouldn't expect that. Additionally the output is the same for the two following executions, and changes with third one.

Comment: @Misery: well, then it looks like a different problem. Unfortunately I also don't see the problem so it is difficult to help...

Comment: Win7 X64 V10.1: ran shift+enter 30 times, all returned the same answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my MacBook Pro with version 10.1, two forms of the same answer are returned, i.e., `Simplify` is timing out. Rather than guessing whether your system is fast enough, capture your "different" results and test whether they are equivalent. If so, then it is a time-out related issue.

```
$Version
```

> "10.1.0  for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)"

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

w = 1/H[x] D[q[x], x] (\[Eta][x] - z) + 
      q[x]/H[x] D[H[x], x] (1 - (\[Eta][x] - z)/(\[Eta][x] - Zb[x])) + 
      q[x]/H[x] D[Zb[x], x];

der = Simplify[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]w\)];

dpdz = -(q[x]/H[x] der + w D[w, z] + g);

int = Integrate[dpdz, {z, Z0, Z1}];

Simplify[int] /. {Z0 -> z, Z1 -> \[Eta], q[x] -> q, 
     H[x] -> H, \[Eta][x] -> \[Eta], Zb[x] -> Zb};

firstCalc = 
  g z - g \[Eta] + (1/(
   2 H^2 (Zb - \[Eta])^2))(z - \[Eta]) (q Derivative[1][H][
        x] + (Zb - \[Eta]) Derivative[1][q][
        x]) ((z - \[Eta]) (Zb - \[Eta]) Derivative[1][q][x] + 
      q ((z - 2 Zb + \[Eta]) Derivative[1][H][x] + 
         2 (-Zb + \[Eta]) Derivative[1][Zb][x])) - 
   1/(2 H^3)q (-((q (z - \[Eta]) (z - 2 Zb + \[Eta]) Derivative[1][H][x]^2)/(
       Zb - \[Eta])) - (z - \[Eta])^2 Derivative[1][H][x] Derivative[1][q][
        x] + (H (z - \[Eta]) (z - 2 Zb + \[Eta]) Derivative[1][H][
        x] Derivative[1][q][x])/(Zb - \[Eta]) + 
      2 q z Derivative[1][H][x] Derivative[1][Zb][x] - 
      2 q \[Eta] Derivative[1][H][x] Derivative[1][Zb][x] + 
      2 H (-z + \[Eta]) Derivative[1][q][x] Derivative[1][Zb][x] + 
      2 H (-z + \[Eta]) Derivative[1][q][x] Derivative[1][\[Eta]][x] - (
      H q (z - \[Eta]) Derivative[1][H][
        x] ((z - \[Eta]) Derivative[1][Zb][
           x] - (z - 2 Zb + \[Eta]) Derivative[1][\[Eta]][
           x]))/(Zb - \[Eta])^2 + (
      H q (z - \[Eta]) (z - 2 Zb + \[Eta]) (H^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x])/(
      Zb - \[Eta]) + H (z - \[Eta])^2 (q^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] - 
      2 H q z (Zb^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] + 
      2 H q \[Eta] (Zb^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]);

subsequentCalc = 
  1/2 (z - \[Eta]) (2 g + 
     1/(H^3 (Zb - \[Eta])^2) (q (Zb - \[Eta]) Derivative[1][H][
          x] ((z - \[Eta]) (Zb - \[Eta]) Derivative[1][q][x] + 
           q ((z - 2 Zb + \[Eta]) Derivative[1][H][x] + 
              2 (-Zb + \[Eta]) Derivative[1][Zb][x])) + 
        H ((z - \[Eta]) (Zb - \[Eta])^2 Derivative[1][q][x]^2 + 
           q (Zb - \[Eta]) ((z - \[Eta]) Derivative[1][H][x] Derivative[1][q][
                x] + (Zb - \[Eta]) (2 Derivative[1][q][x] Derivative[
                   1][\[Eta]][x] - (z - \[Eta]) (q^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x])) + 
           q^2 ((z - 
                 2 Zb + \[Eta]) (Derivative[1][H][
                   x] (Derivative[1][H][x] + Derivative[1][Zb][x] - 
                    Derivative[1][\[Eta]][x]) + (-Zb + \[Eta]) (
                   H^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]) + 
              2 (Zb - \[Eta])^2 (Zb^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]))));

firstCalc == subsequentCalc // Simplify
```

> True